# Access ENV[variable_set_from_passenger] in rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, passenger

I'm running rails with nginx/passenger. Is there a way to pass environment variables from nginx/passenger to the rails app such that it is accessible to a rails initializer(when the app boots up).

By using `passenger_set_cgi_param MYVAR MYVALUE;` , I am able to access it in an action via `request.env["MYVAR"]` .

I need to access it in an initializer. For that how do I set it in nginx/passenger ? I'm guessing reading the env var in the initializer would work via `ENV["MYVAR"]` ?

Does using unicorn or some other web server make things easier ?